# Trying to understand construction of $C^*$-algebra corresponding to a ternary $C^*$-ring from a paper

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Recall that a ternary $C^*$-ring  is a complex Banach space $X$, equipped with a associative ternary product $[.,.,.]:X^3 \to X$ which is linear in outer variables and conjugate linear in middle variable, $\|[a,a,a]\|= \|a\|^3$ and $$\|[a,b,c]\| \leq \| a \| \| b\|\| c\|$$

> Does there exist a unique $C^*$-algebra corresponding to each ternary $C^*$-ring?

$3.2$ Proposition of [this](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/000187088390083X?token=01B8E5AC9D0B68D9B1C3816A5724216F3593567C5DB7B706F1E7859093E031641858701A9AA2ECD58D273F5FFED0E1D4&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210901064606) paper seems to answer what i am looking for. The construction given in paper goes as follows: For $y,z \in X$, consider the bounded linear map $D_{y,z}: X \to X$ defined as $D_{y,z}(x)= [x,y,z]$. Let $V=$ span $\{D_{y,z}: y,z \in X \} \subset L(X)$. After defining like this, the author shows that $V$ is pre $ C^*$-algebra. Finally, author considers the opposite algebra of the norm closure of $V$ to construct the required $C^*$-algebra.

> Can someone please explain me why do we need to consider opposite algebra and the motivation behind this proof?

Comment: The title could perhaps be a bit more explicit: It suggests to me more a general question on how to read a difficult proof, a question of Shakespearean nature in my opinion.

Comment: @RolandBacher: Edited, thanks!

Comment: You can also complete $V$ and obtain a $C^*$-algebra. The opposite $C^*$-algebra of this $C^*$-algebra is then simply the $C^*$-algebra constructed in the paper.

Comment: Your terminology is not correct, if you look closely at the Zettl paper that you link to. What you call a "ternary Banach algebra" is what Zettl calls a "ternary Cstar ring", and the **key point** is the axiom $\Vert [x,x,x,] \Vert= \Vert x\Vert^3$ which is an analogue of the Cstar condition that is one of the axioms for a Cstar algebra. Calling these objects "ternary Banach algebras", as you have done, is misleading since that name should be reserved for an object which does not have the "3-variable Cstar condition"

Comment: It would be good if you could fix the wording of your title and your question. Note also that you have written that X is a "complex associative Banach space" which does not make sense.

Comment: relatedly, it is always good to bear in mind that a general Banach star-algebra without the Cstar condition can behave very differently from a Cstar algebra. The jump from Banach-world to Cstar-world turns out to be a huge leap.

Comment: @YemonChoi: Edited, thank you. Are you aware of any reference for studying representation theory of $C^*$- ternary rings?

Comment: Thank you for editing. I'm afraid I am not very familiar with the literature on these objects, but a logical thing to do, if you have access to MathSciNet, is to look for articles which cite Zettl's paper, and see which other articles they cite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Proposition 3.2 from the article [MR0700979] that you link to gives you the answer for ternary $\rm C^*$-rings. The reason for taking the opposite algebra is that the algebra $V$ acts on the right of $X$ rather than on the left. A right action is the same thing as a left action by the opposite algebra. You can see this right action directly in (3) of this proposition.

As a special case, suppose $X$ is a right Hilbert $\rm C^*$-module over a $\rm C^*$-algebra $A$. Denoting the $A$-valued inner product on $X$ by $\langle x|y\rangle_A$ (which is linear on the right), we get a ternary $\rm C^*$-ring by $[x,y,z] := x\langle y|z\rangle_A$. In this setting, $D_{y,z}$ is right multiplication by $\langle y|z\rangle_A$. All ternary $\rm C^*$-rings are essentially like this one, except that the $A$-valued form need not be positive. (See the intro of the cited article, bottom of p118 after the displayed equation.)