# Second dual $X^{**}$ of ternary $C^*$-ring $X$ is again ternary $C^*$-ring?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Recall that a ternary $C^*$-ring  is a complex Banach space $X$, equipped with a associative ternary product $[.,.,.]:X^3 \to X$ which is linear in outer variables and conjugate linear in middle variable, $\|[a,a,a]\|= \|a\|^3$ and $$\|[a,b,c]\| \leq \| a \| \| b\|\| c\|$$

> Is it known that second dual $X^{**}$ of ternary $C^*$-ring is again ternary $C^*$-ring?

Any references?

Comment: It's an obvious consequence, modulo [Zettle's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402950/), of the same question for C*-algebras.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Would it be enough to observe that $A^{**}$ would be unique $C^*$-algebra corresponding to $X^{**}$ where $A$ is unique  $C^*$-algebra obtained for $X$ by Zettle’s theorem. If yes, why so?

Comment: You should actually read Zettle's paper. The answer to your second question is no and you can read it from Zettle's paper